# Cloning an existing HD into a VMWare boot?

Tags: p2v

How do I clone an existing HD into being used in VMWare?

Comment: You want to create a VM from an existing running computer or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up the VmWare guestto use and HD with an existing drive. Is one of the options that shows when you create the virtual machine.

If you want to clone an existing HD into a virtual HD of a guest then you just need to use a cloning software like [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/) or [Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/redirects/norton/norton_com/) like if it was a real computer.

Comment: I was using VMWare player, now I will be using VMWare Server, has omre feature apparently.

Comment: What of the two things do you want to do? I think that your best option is to use VmWare Workstation.

Comment: I have an old HD, I want to boot it up using its own.

Comment: Ok, then download the Acronis True Image, install it on the host computer and create an image of the disk you want to clone. Then with acronis create a bootable rescue CD and use it when starting the guest machine. Select the image to recover that you did before and you have it!

Answer (score 2):

[VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) would be worth a look. It is also "built-in" to VMware Workstation if you happen to already have that.